# Column Encryption in Informix - SQL -26040: Encrypt VP initialization failed

Tags: encryption, informix

We are using Informix as DB for our application.

We have a new requirement to encrypt one column (ID) alone. The encryption should not be external and should be in DB itself.

IBM explains the encryption procedure in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1024.htm

The steps are as follows:

```
SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD 'credit card number is encrypted' 
   WITH HINT 'Why is this difficult to read?';
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Alice', 
   encrypt_tdes('1234567890123456'));
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Bob',
   encrypt_tdes('2345678901234567'));

SELECT id, DECRYPT_CHAR(creditcard, 
    'credit card number is encrypted') FROM customer;
```

But when I follow the same step, DB is throwing the error in the first step itself (at set encryption password).

> "SQL -26040: Encrypt VP initialization failed."

I am not sure what is the actual issue, as I couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Could someone help us to solve this?

Comment: Sorry I missed this earlier. Please provide platform (operating system and version) information, and also version of Informix (down to the last digit after the second decimal point). How did you install this copy of Informix? Have you ensured that GSKit is installed in the proper place? The installer should do that for you automatically - unless you ran the install as a non-privileged user, or copied the data from another machine, or ... The options on what might be going wrong depend in part on the platform and version. Look for library names containing `libgsk[78]` in `/usr/lib` on Unix.

Comment: Any updates, or did you already find a solution?

Comment: Yes, we installed the Encrypt VP server for informix and then the error got resolved. Sorry I completely missed this.

Comment: Good; I'm glad the issue is resolved.  Now, how to get the question so it has an accepted answer?  Maybe you should write up what you did, and then in a couple of days, accept it.  It won't gain you any benefit, beyond having another question with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Encrypt VP server not present for Informix. We have installed Encrypt VP server and then the encryption was successful.

Thanks,